# jquery.form & jquery.validate: No POST data submitted in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

When users submit my from in IE8, with or without compatibility mode, the form does the AJAX call, but no POST data is sent. Below is my jQuery.validate and jQuery.form code:

```
var v = jQuery("#enterfrm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                target: "#result",
                success: function() {
                    $("#enterfrm").hide();
                }
            });
        },
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            reportto: {
                required: true
            },
            jobtitle: {
                required: true
            },
            dept: {
                required: true
            },
            paystatus: {
                required: true
            },
            reason: {
                required: true
            },
            prefstartdate: {
                required: true
            },
            sthour: {
                required: true
            },
            edhour: {
                required: true
            },
            jbdescex: {
                required: true
            },
            positionchg: {
                required: true
            },
            minexp: {
                required: true
            },
            adrecreq: {
                required: true
            },
            comsug: {
                required: false
            },
            org: {
                required: true
            },
            origemail: {
                required: true
            },
            // //
            replacing: {
                required: function(element) {
                    return $("#reason").val() == "Replacement";
                }
            },
            replacetitle: {
                required: function(element) {
                    return $("#reason").val() == "Replacement";
                }
            },
            justify: {
                required: function(element) {
                    return $("#reason").val() == "New Position";
                }
            },
            length: {
                required: function(element) {
                    return $("#paystatus").val() == "Temporary - In House" || $("#paystatus").val() == "Temporary - Outside";
                }
            },
            purpose: {
                required: function(element) {
                    return $("#jbdescex").val() == "No" || $("#positionchg").val() == "Yes";
                }
            },
            duties: {
                required: function(element) {
                    return $("#jbdescex").val() == "No" || $("#positionchg").val() == "Yes";
                }
            },   
            sthour: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 8
                //notEqTime: true
            },
            edhour: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 8 //,
                //notEqTime: true
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is what FireBug Lite captures:

```
ResponseHeaders
Date Mon, 17 Jan 2011 13:56:25 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.12 with Suhosin-Patch mod_perl/2.0.2 Perl/v5.8.8
X-Powered-By PHP/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.12
Keep-Alive timeout=15, max=100
Connection Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Content-Type text/html

RequestHeaders
Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
Accept */*
```

There is nothing under the POST tab. This all works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and IE with Chrome Frame. Am I missing something as far as the problem is concerned?

**EDIT**
I have tried this with a GET request as well now and that does not work either.

Comment: Is there a chance the browser is going into quirks mode?

Comment: @Yads I have used the Developer Tool for IE and made sure it was not in quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

looks like jQuery.Form uses `$.param(a)` to serialize the form, I've only had success getting IE to create proper POST Data with `$.param(a, true)` See here. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

You can use traditional serialization globally by doing `$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`

Comment: Would you suggest just using GET data instead?

Comment: @Badger I just realized that this is probably not the right answer as I misremembered my issue. My issue was not getting ASP.NET MVC to reserialize the PostData correctly. You can try setting the global `traditional` flag, but it probably won't help.

Comment: you are right, the traditional flag did not help any. I also tried a GET request and that did nothing to help either. Though I think a serialization problem may be the right direction. I may just abandon the AJAX form submission and hope that fixes the issue.

Comment: by just doing a normal form submission, and not an AJAX one it works fine.